# The term 'METEOR_PACKAGE_DIRS=packages' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: meteor, ohif

I ran this **METEOR_PACKAGE_DIRS="packages" meteor --settings config/orthancDICOMWeb.json**  this in my ohif application root. but it gives a error "METEOR_PACKAGE_DIRS=packages : The term 'METEOR_PACKAGE_DIRS=packages' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable  program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again".My packege file is located in the project root.My OS is windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
METEOR_PACKAGE_DIRS="packages" meteor --settings config/orthancDICOMWeb.json
```

seems to be in unix/linux format.

On windows you may use `set` to first set the environment variables (wrapping your code in a small batch script):

```
set METEOR_PORT=3090
set METEOR_SETTINGS=config/orthancDICOMWeb.json
set METEOR_PACKAGE_DIRS=packages
call meteor --port=%METEOR_PORT% --settings %METEOR_SETTINGS$
```